# Using draggable and rotation - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran across an issue when trying to use `draggable()` and having a rotating feature in JQuery.  Here is what happens, when a user clicks on a div and drags it, it works great.  But if a user just clicks it will rotate a little.  If it is rotated at all, when you try to drag the div, it jumps up a little bit.  I am not to sure as to why this is?

I think it has to do with, not receiving the proper `left` and `top` I have defined on the div.  Let me know your ideas.

Code:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable(); <-- implementation of the draggable feature in JQuery UI
```

UPDATE:

So I have a custom rotation and move feature that will move it and rotate based on when user clicks buttons and whatnot.  Now when they use that to move/rotate, it does not jump.  It only jumps up when using the mouse to rotate and drag it.  (IF you don't rotate it, using the mouse to drag it; it works fine)

Code example of part of move/rotate feature:

```
if(direction == "big")
    {
        //get last x and y cordinates
            var x = $("#draggable").css('left');
            var y =$("#draggable").css('top');

        function drawBig() {
            //define new font size
            howMuch = startFontSize + howMuch;
            //define var with new font size
            startFontSize = howMuch;

            //define text font size and family
            ctx.font = howMuch + 'px ' + fFamily;
            //fill with the text
            ctx.fillText(text, 10, 100);
            //draw text
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

            ctx.drawImage(img,10, 20, 500, 100);
        }
        //get values
        var current = $(".activeText a div").attr('id');
        var text = $("#fontEnter").val();
        //get font family
        var fFamily = $(".activeText a .fontType-cont").val();
        // default remove old
        $(".customize-Container #draggable").remove();
        //create a canvas for image converting
        $(".customize-Container").append("<div id='draggable'><canvas id='"+current+"'></canvas></div>");
        //create canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById(current),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = document.createElement('img');


        //draw it
        img.onload = drawBig;
        if($(".activeGColor").find('img').attr('src'))
        {
            img.src = $(".activeGColor").find('img').attr('src');   
        }
        else // <!-- default color = metallic
        {
            $(".graphicsDrop").text("Metallic");
            img.src = '../wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/controller/custamizeStyle/swatches/Metallic.png';
        }

        //change where draggable is located:
        $( "#draggable" ).css('top' , y);
        $( "#draggable" ).css('left' , x);

        //check rotation
        if (rotation != 0)
        {
            $("#draggable").css({ transform : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)' });
        }
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    }
```

Notice that the #draggable container is also becoming a draggable so the user could use pad I created or the mouse (IT is only when using mouse that the div jumps up when you rotated it.)

Comment: Can you add a fiddle? Which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm not clear from your question, are you implementing a custom rotation feature? Or are you just seeing some unexpected rotating from draggable()?

Comment: Chrome, it happens for all of them. IE, FF, Chrome..

Comment: See update I just put in.

Comment: A fiddle would be make it a lot easier

Comment: I started a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/y8L7K/ Unfortunately, the code you provided isn't enough for me to get it working. If you could update that fiddle so we can see the error, we'll try to help you fix it.